# Revit API & Dynamo, Handling Variable Input Types

Tags: revit-api, revitpythonshell

Per this thread on the Dynamo forums: http://dynamobim.org/forums/topic/how-to-handle-variable-list-lengthnesting-in-custom-nodes-python/, I'd like to find a way to handle variable inputs for a custom node.

Here's an example script that changes the family type of an element:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('ProtoGeometry')
from Autodesk.DesignScript.Geometry import *

# Import ToDSType(bool) extension method
clr.AddReference("RevitNodes")
import Revit
clr.ImportExtensions(Revit.Elements)

# Import DocumentManager and TransactionManager
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")
import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager

from System.Collections.Generic import *

# Import RevitAPI
clr.AddReference("RevitAPI")
import Autodesk

doc = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument
uiapp = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentUIApplication
app = uiapp.Application


doc =  DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentDBDocument
app =  DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentUIApplication.Application


inputItems = []

for i in IN[0]:
    inputItems.append(UnwrapElement(i))

toggle = IN[1]
familyType = UnwrapElement(IN[2]).Id
elementlist = []


TransactionManager.Instance.EnsureInTransaction(doc)

if toggle == True:
    for item in inputItems:
        item.ChangeTypeId(familyType)
        elementlist.append(item)

else:
    None

TransactionManager.Instance.TransactionTaskDone()

OUT = elementlist
```

I'd like to find a way that I can handle an input that is a list, a nested list, OR a single item (non-list) like the image below:

[image]

For the latter two, I can just use a list.flatten. The problem is finding a way to handle all three types of lists/elements.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case if your goal is to use Python to handle all different input structures I would suggest something like this:

if you only want to perform an operation on an item (let's say add +1) regardless of the data structure, I use recursion and a simple  `isinstance (IN[0], list)`  check like so:

```
#The inputs to this node will be stored as a list in the IN variable.
dataEnteringNode = IN

def ProcessList(_func, _list):
    return map( lambda x: ProcessList(_func, x) if type(x)==list else _func(x), _list )

def AddOne(item):
    return item + 1

if isinstance (IN[0], list):
    output = ProcessList(AddOne, IN[0])
else:
    output = AddOne(IN[0])

#Assign your output to the OUT variable.
OUT = output
```

Here's an example in Dynamo operating on different structures of data:

[image]

This approach is pretty good because it allows you to output the exact same structure as was inputted. I use this a lot.

Comment: This works. Although for what I was doing, defining the input works equally well (var[]). I do think that allowing the output to be the same as the input is a nice trick.

Comment: Sure, I understand, but the question was about using Python in this case to handle different input structures. I believe my answer is correct, however there are other possibilities. They were brought up during the discussion on the Dynamo Forum. I was focusing on solving it with Python.